# C# using reflection to get type of the objects in a list

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class that contains a list of another class. How do i get the properties of the other class from just the list?

Im currently doing something like this:

```
private string ChildString(Type type)
{
    string temp = "";
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType))
        {
            //How do i get the properties here?
        }
        if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass && prop.PropertyType.Assembly.FullName == typeof(T).Assembly.FullName)
        {
            temp += prop.Name;
            ChildString(prop.PropertyType);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Use `prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]` to get the generic argument type.

Comment: Thank you, this was what i was looking for